# Accessing useAuth0 hook data via redux thunk action with axios instance

Tags: react-redux, axios, auth0, redux-toolkit

Have a bit of an issue attempting to get Auth0 info on the logged-in user with our current architecture.

We have `redux` with `@reduxjs/toolkit` & `react-redux` as our state management tool.

We use `axios` to make HTTP requests via redux-thunk actions.

And now we have a part of our application that allows users to signup/login with `Auth0`.

So, an example of our problem.

Currently our redux store is setup with some reducers

```
/* eslint-disable import/no-cycle */
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';

const createStore = (initialState?: any) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: {
      // reducers are here
    },
    middleware: [thunk],
    preloadedState: initialState,
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

Then we attached that to a `Provider` at the base of our application

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import createStore from '../store/createStore';

const App = () => {
  return (
      <Provider store={createStore()}>
        //
      </Provider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

We have an axios instance function that uses `axios` to make HTTP requests and handles errors.

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import { getAuthSignature } from '../utils/auth';

export const API_URL = process.env.API_HOST;

const axiosInstance = async <T = any>(requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> => {
  const { token } = await getAuthSignature();
  // I need to access auth0 data here
  const { getAccessTokenSilently, isAuthenticated, isLoading, loginWithRedirect, user } = auth0;

  if (!token) {
    const tokenErr = {
      title: 'Error',
      message: 'Missing Authentication Token',
      success: false,
    };
    throw tokenErr;
  }

  try {
    let accessToken = token;
    // Update authorization token if auth0 user
    if(auth0) {
      if(isAuthenticcation && user) accessToken = await getAccessTokenSilently({ audience });
      else loginWithRedirect();
    }
    const result = await axios({
      ...requestConfig,
      headers: {
        ...requestConfig.headers,
        authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`,
      },
    });

    return result;
  } catch (error: any) {
    if (error.response) {
      if ([401, 403].includes(error.response.status)) {
        window.location = '/';
      }

      const contentType = error?.response?.headers?.['content-type'];
      const isHTMLRes = contentType && contentType.indexOf('text/html') !== -1;

      const errObj = {
        status: error?.response?.status,
        statusText: error?.response?.statusText,
        errorMessage: isHTMLRes && error?.response?.text && (await error?.response?.text()),
        error,
      };

      throw errObj;
    }

    throw error;
  }
};

export default axiosInstance;
```

This in an example of a thunk action, we would have something like this that uses the axios instance mentioned above to make the HTTP requests.

```
import axios, { API_URL } from '../../services/axios';
import { Result } from '../../types/test';
import { AppThunk } from '../../store/store';
import { setResults, setResultsLoading, setTableLoading } from './test.slice';

type DefaultThunk = () => AppThunk<Promise<void>>;

const getResults: DefaultThunk = () => async () => {
  dispatch(setTableLoading(true));

  try {
    const result = await axios<Result[]>(
      {
        method: 'GET',
        url: `${API_URL}/test`,
      },
    );

    dispatch(setResults(result.data));
  } catch (err: any) {
    console.log({ err });
  } finally {
    dispatch(setResultsLoading(false));
    dispatch(setTableLoading(false));
  }
};

export default getResults;
```

We then dispatch our thunk actions to make HTTP requests and update reducer states in our React components.

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import getResults from '../../reducers/test/test.thunk';

const TestComponent = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getResults());
  }, []);

  return (
    //
  );
};

export default TestComponent;
```

My problem is that I have no idea how to integrate `Auth0` gracefully into the current flow, so I do not have to make checks in every react component that uses a thunk action.

Basically I need access to values within the `useAuth0` hook from `@auth0/auth0-react` for example `getAccessTokenSilently`, `isAuthenticated`, `user` & `loginWithRedirect`. Just to name a few.

We can't use the `useAuth0` hook in the axios instance file, as it's not a react component/hook, nor is the thunk file.

So I'm not sure how and where the best place is to get the data so that it is accessible in the axios file, as aforementioned without having to pass it as an argument or something in every redux thunk action.

Perhaps we just need a different approach to the current flow of dispatch > action > axios request?

Is there any way to pass this data in as middleware to redux?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you edit the post to include an example where you ***are*** using the `useAuth0` hook and returned values? In other words, what has the `useAuth0` hook to do with any of the currently shared code snippets? See [mcve].

Comment: I mentioned here > `So I'm not sure how and where the best place is to get the data so that it is accessible in the axios file`. But I have updated the question specifically where - https://stackoverflow.com/posts/74354278/revisions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe you'd be able to use a middleware to "sniff" out the `auth0` context value because middlewares run *outside* React. What I'd suggest here is to create a wrapper component that sits between the `Auth0Provider` and redux `Provider` components that accesses the `auth0` context and dispatches an action to save it into the redux state where it can be selected via `useSelector` or accessed directly from `store.getState()`.

Fortunately it appears the `auth0` context value is already memoized [here](https://github.com/auth0/auth0-react/blob/master/src/auth0-provider.tsx#L402-L426) so it should be able to be directly consumed as a stable reference within the app.

Rough Example:

```
import { useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import { useAuth0 } from '@auth0/auth0-react';
import { actions } from '../path/to/auth0Slice';

const Auth0Wrapper = ({ children }) => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  const auth0 = useAuth0();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(actions.setAuthContext(auth0));
  }, [auth0]);

  return children;
};
```

Create and export the store for consumption within the app.

Store

```
import { configureStore } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
...
import auth0Reducer from '../path/to/auth0Slice';
...

const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  auth0: auth0Reducer,
  ... other root state reducers ...
});

const createStore = (initialState?: any) => {
  return configureStore({
    reducer: rootReducer,
    middleware: [thunk],
    preloadedState: initialState,
  });
};

export default createStore;
```

App

```
import Auth0Wrapper from '../path/to/Auth0Wrapper';
import createStore from '../path/to/store';

const store = createStore();

const App = () => {
  return (
    <Auth0Provider ......>
      <Provider store={store}>
        <Auth0Wrapper>
          // ... JSX ...
        </Auth0Wrapper>
      </Provider>
    </Auth0Provider>
  );
};

export store;

export default App;
```

Create a new Auth0 state slice.

```
import { createSlice } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';

const auth0Slice = createSlice({
  name: 'auth0',
  initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    setAuthContext: (state, action) => {
      return action.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const actions = {
  ...auth0Slice.actions,
};

export default auth0Slice.reducer;
```

From here you can import the exported `store` object and access the current state inside the axios setup.

```
import axios, { AxiosRequestConfig, AxiosResponse } from 'axios';
import store from '../path/to/App';
import { getAuthSignature } from '../utils/auth';

export const API_URL = process.env.API_HOST;

const axiosInstance = async <T = any>(requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> => {
  const { token } = await getAuthSignature();

  const { auth0 } = store.getState(); // <-- access current state from store

  const {
    getAccessTokenSilently,
    isAuthenticated,
    isLoading,
    loginWithRedirect,
    user
  } = auth0;

  ...
};
```

Comment: This approached worked, I had actually gone down the middleware route passing the auth0 return values from the useAuth0 hook down into a function that creates the store, but I think this is a much better solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The hook methods are great if you're not using redux, but since you are, the recommended approach is to use the spa js library - https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/.

Here's a code example for a rest call:

```js
document.getElementById('call-api').addEventListener('click', async () => {
  const accessToken = await auth0.getTokenSilently();
  const result = await fetch('https://myapi.com', {
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    }
  });
  const data = await result.json();
  console.log(data);
});
```

https://github.com/auth0/auth0-spa-js/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#calling-an-api

This is easily adaptable to thunks, in your case, inside of your axios instance ie:

```js
const axiosInstance = async <T = any>(requestConfig: AxiosRequestConfig): Promise<AxiosResponse<T>> => {
  const accessToken = await auth0.getTokenSilently();
  // handle token and request
}
```

The auth0 with hooks is more like a convenience library, but it's built on top of spa js.